# Windows Tool For Enable/DIsable SSL TLS

Tags: windows, ssl

Some Month ago i saw a tool link in stackoverflow for **disable/enable SSL, TLS 1,TLS 1.1,TLS 1.2,TLS 1.3**
So there is no need to manipulate registry directly.
But i can not find it.
Please introduce me a good tool for that purpose.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is free and quite good: https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/

Comment: You are the best. I Was looking for that.